# Testing an inside function with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I need to test a function called "cache". It is a function wrapper, which takes a function and caches its results depending on the arguments, that were applied to the function.

#### This is how I implemented the function

```
const cache = (func) => {
    let cache = {};
    let stringFromArgs;
    return (...args) => {
        let n = args[0];
        if (stringFromArgs === JSON.stringify(args)) {
           return cache[n];
        } else  {
            stringFromArgs = JSON.stringify(args)
            cache[n] = func(...args);
            return cache[n];
        }
    }
}
```

So this is how it works:

```
let complexFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
 };



let cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);


cachedFunction(1, 2); // complex function should be executed
cachedFunction(1, 2); // complex function should not be invoked again,
                      // instead the cached result should be returned
cachedFunction(1, 5); // should be executed, because the method wasn't invoked before with these arguments
```

When the function cachedFunction is called twice with the same arguments, that inside function should be called only once. Second time the result should come from the cache. I need to test that using sinon.js. Or maybe there is another way to test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`cache.js`:

```js
const cache = (func) => {
  let cache = {};
  let stringFromArgs;
  return (...args) => {
    let n = args[0];
    if (stringFromArgs === JSON.stringify(args)) {
      return cache[n];
    } else {
      stringFromArgs = JSON.stringify(args);
      cache[n] = func(...args);
      return cache[n];
    }
  };
};

module.exports = cache;
```

`cache.test.js`:

```js
const cache = require('./cache');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('62426207', () => {
  it('should call complex function', () => {
    let complexFunction = sinon.stub().callsFake((arg1, arg2) => {
      return arg1 + arg2;
    });
    let cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);
    cachedFunction(1, 2);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(complexFunction, 1, 2);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(complexFunction);
  });

  it('should not call complex function again', () => {
    let complexFunction = sinon.stub().callsFake((arg1, arg2) => {
      return arg1 + arg2;
    });
    let cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);
    cachedFunction(1, 2);
    let ret = cachedFunction(1, 2);
    expect(ret).to.be.equal(3);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(complexFunction, 1, 2);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(complexFunction);
  });

  it('should call complex function if arguments are different', () => {
    let complexFunction = sinon.stub().callsFake((arg1, arg2) => {
      return arg1 + arg2;
    });
    let cachedFunction = cache(complexFunction);
    let ret1 = cachedFunction(1, 2);
    expect(ret1).to.be.equal(3);
    let ret2 = cachedFunction(1, 5);
    expect(ret2).to.be.equal(6);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(complexFunction, 1, 2);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(complexFunction, 1, 5);
    sinon.assert.calledTwice(complexFunction);
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  62426207
    ✓ should call complex function
    ✓ should not call complex function again
    ✓ should call complex function if arguments are different


  3 passing (18ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 cache.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```